# How to perform mathematical calculations for each record in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a help in order to make a MySQL query.

I want to calculate the commision for each product that i have in my tablet and then create a total for the price and a total of the commissions.

The total of the price can be easily calculated using the SUM(price)
for example :

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed"
```

On the same query how i can calculate the commission of each product and then add it to the total of the commissions?

For example

> product A: $30(product price) x 3%(commision) = $0.90 (Commission)
>
> product B: $70(product price) x 7%(commision) = $4.90 (Commission)

The total of each product will be 30+70 = 100 and the total commision will be 0.90 + 4.90 = 5.80

So at the end my query will return back 100 and 5.80. How i can do it this in MySQL?

Thank you

Comment: `select price*0.03 as threepercent from ...`. do whatever math you want in the query.

Comment: SELECT SUM(price) AS TOTAL , SUM(SELECT price * commision FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed" ) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed"

like this?

Comment: no. just `sum(price*commission)`. the sum()-type aggregate functions are applied on a per-row basis, so you can refer to any fields you want that are in the result set. no need for a sub-query.

Comment: i want with one query to return back the commission of all products(sum the commision of each product seperate) and the price total

Comment: Can you setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some data?

Answer (score 0):

Here how i solved it

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(price) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed" ) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed") AS TOTAL , (SELECT SUM(price * commision) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed" ) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed") AS commission FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed" ) FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this page looking for an answer, you can just add the equation in the `SUM` function - like someone mentioned in a comment on the question.

The resulting query would look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS TOTAL , SUM(price * commision) AS commission FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE WHERE ORDER_STATUS = "Completed"
```

You can read about the `SUM` function [here](https://w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp)